# Xna: Texture2D from a png file

Tags: xna, game-design, textures, tiles, map-editor

I'm making a tile based game, and I'm working for support of tilesets. I'm trying to make it so that a Texture2D is set as a chosen PNG file. I can do this with no problem f I load the image into the content pipeline, but the level editor will be used by people without access to the content pipeline. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You can call the [Texture2D.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.fromstream.aspx) static method. Just pass it a stream to the png file. I'm pretty sure it works without the content pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late for Raj but for anyone else...

```
        string PictureLocation = @"D:\PictureName.png";
        Texture2D Newtexture =  LoadPicture(PictureLocation);

        string PictureDestination = @"D:\NewPictureName.png";
        SavePicture(PictureDestination, Newtexture);

    public static Texture2D LoadPicture(string Filename)
    {
        FileStream setStream = File.Open(Filename, FileMode.Open);
        Texture2D NewTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(graphicsDevice, setStream);
        setStream.Dispose();
        return NewTexture;
    }

    public static void SavePicture(string Filename, Texture2D TextureToSave)
    {
        FileStream setStream = File.Open(Filename, FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(setStream);
        TextureToSave.SaveAsPng(setStream, TextureToSave.Width, TextureToSave.Height);
        setStream.Dispose();
    }
```

Reading in and saving in a new location for PNG and JPEG (I think they are the only supported, but that should be good enough :).

Hope this helps anybody else with a similar problem. Stoort.